# ASP.NET 4 Routing catch all

Tags: routes, webforms, http-status-code-404, asp.net-4.0

I have an ASP.NET 4 WebForms application which is using routing. I would like to catch the 404's for routes that do not exist:

```
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("404", "{*url}", "~/error");
```

Problem is, this will also cause a mapping to `/error` for pages like `ImageHandler.ashx` and `Resource.axd`.

So I add this:

```
    RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd");
    RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{handler}.ashx");
```

But this only ignores Resource.axd in the root directory, not in for example `/scripts/Resource.axd`.

How can I accomplish this? Or what Contraints should I set for the catch all PageRoute so it will only catch directories?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{*resource}.axd");
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{*handler}.ashx");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem with a hybrid WebForms/MCV3 application which brought me to this question.  Basically only root level axd files were handled properly, anything outside of that was trying to be routed to a controller.

My situation maybe different, but in the end I found doing something like this worked:

```
routes.Ignore("{*allaxd}", new { allaxd = @".*\.axd(/.*)?" });
```

I don't know much about Ignore and IgnoreRoutes so there could be a better/less greedy solution, but it's working.